# why might nmap on a computer be reporting port 443 as closed on some but not all computers?

Tags: networking, port, tcp, wireshark, nmap

When I run `nmap event-bridge.twilio.com` on roughly half the computers in my network I get this:

```
PORT    STATE   SERVICE
443/tcp closed  https
```

When I run it on the other half of the computers in my network I get this:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
```

I installed Wireshark to capture the packets and on the computers that have the issue the computer sends a SYN request and the server responds with RST but on the computers without the issue the server responds with SYN/ACK (which I'd expect).

I updated the hosts file one of the computers with the issue to point to the same IP address that one of the computers without the issue was using for event-bridge.twilio.com and that didn't help.

Neither the router or firewall have any rules blocking event-bridge.twilio.com so I'm at a loss. And the fact that it's only half the computers is leaving me pretty perplexed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it happen with other website ?

Comment: @S.Brottes - nope - just `event-bridge.twilio.com`

Comment: So you are doing nmap FROM various computers, TO, just one computer?

Comment: @barlop - correct

Comment: I gtg out but have wireshark on the one computer and a computer that shows it as open and a compute rthat shows it as closed So then you can follow the packet along

Comment: Is there some difference between both halves of the network?

Comment: @harrymc - wireless seems to be working fine. Wired is mixed. It works for some people but not for other people on the wired network. Beyond that I haven't been able to identify patterns in the effected computers that don't also apply to the non-affected computers

Comment: I think you will need to show the schema for the network architecture, to get a useful answer.